# How can the following Python code be implemented in Golang?

Tags: python, go

How to design interfaces and structs in Go to achieve sample Python code effects?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Device(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def fn(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def sync(self):
        print("Start Sync ...")
        self.fn()
        print("Sync Done.")


class PC(Device):

    def fn(self):
        print("PC fn!!!")


class Router(Device):

    def fn(self):
        print("Router fn")

    def sync(self):
        print("Router sync ...")
        super().sync()
        print("Router sync.")


def start_sync(d: Device):
    d.sync()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = PC()
    r = Router()
    start_sync(p)  # Run p.fn()
    print("-" * 60)
    start_sync(r)  # Run r.sync()
```

- Router rewrites the sync and fn methods.
- PC rewrites the fn method.

I tried this, but since the function arguments is Device, it always calls Device's sync method.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IDevice interface {
    fn()
}
type Device struct {
    IDevice
}

func (d Device) sync() {
    fmt.Println("device sync ...")
    d.fn()
    fmt.Println("device done.")
}

type PC struct{}

func (PC) fn() {
    fmt.Println("PC fn")
}

type Router struct{}

func (Router) fn()   { fmt.Println("Router fn") }
func (Router) sync() { fmt.Println("Router Sync") }

func start(d Device) {
    d.sync()
}

func main() {
    start(Device{IDevice: PC{}})
    start(Device{IDevice: Router{}}) // This is Device Sync. I want to run Router Sync.
}
```

I am a beginner in Golang and would like to know how to design the appropriate interfaces and structs in Go to achieve similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// Device is an interface representing a device.
type Device interface {
    Fn()
    Sync()
}

// PC represents a PC device.
type PC struct{}

// Fn implements the Fn method for PC.
func (p PC) Fn() {
    fmt.Println("PC fn!!!")
}

// Sync implements the Sync method for PC.
func (p PC) Sync() {
    fmt.Println("Start Sync ...")
    p.Fn()
    fmt.Println("Sync Done.")
}

// Router represents a Router device.
type Router struct{}

// Fn implements the Fn method for Router.
func (r Router) Fn() {
    fmt.Println("Router fn")
}

// Sync implements the Sync method for Router.
func (r Router) Sync() {
    fmt.Println("Router sync ...")
    r.Fn()
    fmt.Println("Router sync.")
}

// StartSync starts the synchronization process for a device.
func StartSync(d Device) {
    d.Sync()
}

func main() {
    p := PC{}
    r := Router{}

    StartSync(p) // Run p.Sync()
    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("*", 20))
    StartSync(r) // Run r.Sync()
}
```

[sample-go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/a6eTVvTKiCL)

**Check this out. you will gain a better understanding**..!